# MySQL select value from table where field in (x,y,z) cycled output

Tags: mysql

I have a query like this:

```
select value from table 
where field_id in (52,54,58,59,60,61,62,55,53,132) and item_id = 16 
order by FIELD (field_id,52,54,58,59,60,61,62,55,53,132);
```

Currently, the output is grouped by field_id, so all values of field_id 52 are spit out, then all values of field_id 54, etc.

Is there a way inherent to MySQL to loop the output so one value for each field_id is output then back 'round to the beginning for another pass?  Trying to do it within a sql native query, rather than using PHP.

Comment: What _one_ value?`max`, `min` or something else?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you said *Currently, the output is grouped by field_id,* and confuse most people here. Because according to your query it is not grouped. It is just ordered.

But you need it. So just try to group (that will bring one value per field_id):

```
SELECT field_id, MAX(`value`), AVG(`value`) 
FROM `table` 
WHERE field_id IN (52,54,58,59,60,61,62,55,53,132) 
  AND item_id = 16 
GROUP BY field_id
ORDER BY FIELD (field_id,52,54,58,59,60,61,62,55,53,132);
```

and you can use any aggregate functions like MIN, MAX, AVG to use one of values if multiple per field_id.